# Error on routes array on angular2 routing

Tags: angular

this is my app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CronoComponent } from './crono/crono.component';
import { ClockFactory } from './classes/clockFactory';
import { PruebaComponent } from './prueba/prueba.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo:'home'},
  { path:'crono', component:'CronoComponent' },
  { path:'prueba', component:'PruebaComponent' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CronoComponent,
    PruebaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [ClockFactory],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have an error on the routes array declaration ,says that the content of routes is not assignable to a Routes array.This is the complete error message that it shows

```
Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; } | { path: string; component: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; } | { path: string; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
    Type '{ path: string; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
      Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'
```

Comment: You can use `redirectTo` only when using `pathMatch`.
Example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-config

Comment: I've chenged for `{ path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full'}` with the same result

Comment: That was the problem than you @Sandrooco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To use `redirectTo`, you have to use `pathMatch`.
2. The `component`s shouldn't be strings but the component itself.

[Official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-config)